# Access ember js object from template

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have an ember controller as follows

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
   edwin:{
    uno:'hola',
    dos:'hola dos',
    tres:'hola tres'
  }
});
```

I my template I need the value of the property edwin, if I get the property as

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  {{edwin.dos}}
  </script>
```

It works fine,
but I need to select the object element from other variable, when I try

```
 <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  {{edwin['dos']}}
  </script>
```

or

```
 <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  {{edwin[myvar]}}
  </script>
```

I can't display the value
this is my jsbin

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xupuse/1/edit

any suggestions

Comment: This isn't supported in handlebars.  if you can provide a real use case I'd be glad to provide you with an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

The closest you'll get it creating some dynamic property in the controller, based on another property.  The real problem will be if the other property changes, ember won't know to update it.  In the example below, if edwin.xxxx changed the computed property wouldn't know*, whereas if dynamo changed it would know (since it's watching it).

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  edwin:{
    uno:'hola',
    dos:'hola dos',
    tres:'hola tres'
  },
  dynamo: 'uno',
  dynamoProperty: function(){
    return this.get('edwin.' + this.get('dynamo'));
  }.property('dynamo')
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/beziq/1/edit

*I'm kind of lying here, you could specify each and every property on edwin and it would always be marked dirty, regardless of whether or not it applied to dynamoProperty a la

```
  dynamoProperty: function(){
    return this.get('edwin.' + this.get('dynamo'));
  }.property('dynamo', 'edwin.{uno,dos,tres}')
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/beziq/2/edit

Comment: That's almost what I need to achive with this differences: 1. The controller is an ArrayController. 2. The dinamo property is not part of the controller instead is part of the model. Y need the property to apply a css based in the state of the model row.